# Generating sitemaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sitemap, google-search-console

I have a rails app and I figured I should probably generate a sitemap, but the problem is more related to best practices or the acceptable data to put in a site map... firstly do you guys even recommend creating a sitemap.xml file?

Secondly, say we have like a social networking site, wouldn't the XML file grow so insanely large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/queso/sitemap). As for the second: yes, it would. You should probably not have an item for every single record in your DB - maybe just one item that links to a paginated index.

Comment: I guess this works, it's pretty old, but seems to work, I hacked some stuff together based off of this.